# Layout with column and absolute image

Tags: html, css, vue.js, layout

I'm trying to make a website and I want to do a page with that layout:

```
------------------------------------------
|    A title     |                       |
|     There      |  A non square         |
|                |------     image       |
|    A long description |        there   |
|            By there   |                |
|                       |  Some text     |
|                       |  over the img  |
|                       |                |
------------------------------------------
```

I'm using vuejs and vuetify, I have tried to do something like that:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; width="60%"; background-image: url('/Background1.png');> </div>
<v-row>
  <v-col cols=5>Title there </v-col>
  <v-col cols=7><v-col>
<v-row>
<v-row>
  <v-col cols=8>A long description by there</v-col>
  <v-col cols=4>Some text over the image </v-col>
<v-row>
```

That works with my resolution 1920*1080, but when I downsize the window, it goes wrong because the position of the second row doesn't match the "edge" of the image.

I know it's because I used 'position:absolute' but I don't know how to do it in an other way.

Some help would be great ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use CSS grid?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="longDescription">Long description</div>
  <div class="img">Non-square image</div>
  <div class="textOverImg">Text over image</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* STYLING */

.container > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.longDescription {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.img {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.textOverImg {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

/* CSS GRID */

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40vw 10vw 40vw;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 20px);
}

.title {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}

.longDescription {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 4 / span 7;
  z-index: 10;
}

.img {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 5;
}

.textOverImg {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 5 / span 6;
}
```

You can see the effect here: https://codepen.io/Sa1m0n/pen/jOqZPOy.

Comment: Thank you ! Didin't know that such a thing exist !